# Can't update Boolean value of Account object

Tags: apex, boolean

I cannot update update this Boolean value in Apex. What is going wrong? The if statement, and the fact that the front end representation is a checkbox, proves that it is indeed a boolean value. I am new to Apex so I feel its a basic misunderstanding of how it works. Can anyone help me out?

Here is the code that I'm executing in an Anonymous Window.

```
Account acc = new Account(Name='Test Name');
if (acc.Do_Not_Contact__pc == false) {
    System.debug('DNC is false');
} else {
    System.debug('DNC is true');
}
insert acc;
acc.Do_Not_Contact__pc = true;
update acc;
```

It fails on the second to last line, displaying the following message:

```
System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 001W000000fFiVbIAK; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, Account: bad field names on insert/update call: Do_Not_Contact__pc: [Do_Not_Contact__pc]
```

What's particularly frustrating is that when I change the second to last line to

```
acc.Do_Not_Contact__pc = 'true';
```

I get an error stating that I cannot assign a String to a Boolean value

**Edit 1**:
Here is an image showing the Account field configuration

[image: Field Configuration]

**Edit 2**:
Full field configuration
[image: Full field configuration]

Comment: Are you sure `Do_Not_Contact__pc` is the right field name? Have you set up Person Accounts in your org? Can you include a screenshot of your field configuration?

Comment: I'm certain that `Do_Not_Contact__pc` is the right field name. When I change `Do_Not_Contact__pc` to `Do_Not_Contact__c` on line 2 I get an error `Variable does not exist: Do_Not_Contact__c`

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include a clear screenshot of your field configuration.

Comment: I have edited to include a screeenshot

Comment: No the entire field configuration. You should be able to click into that field's detail view and see more information.

Comment: I have updated my post again to show what you've asked. As you can see I cannot click into the field's detail view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the RecordTypeId to a Person Account record type, or you won't be able to use "PC" fields. Also, you **cannot** use the Name field for a Person Account, because it's used only on Business Accounts. Use FirstName, LastName, etc to set the name.

```
Id personAccountRTId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE IsPersonType=true LIMIT 1].Id;

Account record = new Account(LastName=..., RecordTypeId=personAccountRTId, Do_Not_Contact__pc=...);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why was I able to view and change the value of the `__pc` field? The execution only failed when I tried to `update`

Comment: @Briscoooe Apex Code doesn't validate if the person account fields are valid, because it doesn't know if the account is a person account. It's the DML runtime that has to determine if the fields submitted are valid or not.